# Let m be the least common multiple of a,b and c be another common multiple. Prove that m divides c.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, least-common-multiple

I have tried to solve the problem. I have started by assigning m=(a*b)/d, where d is the greatest common divisor of a and b. Then I set up c = a*q. That is where I am stuck. I am really not sure what to do next.

Comment: $c$ divides $m$? Don't you mean, prove $m$ divides $c$?

Comment: I am sorry... you are right it is m divides c.!!

Comment: Let $c=mq+r$ with $0\le r<m$ and show that $r$ is also a common multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $c = rm+d$ where $r$ is some integer and $d < m$. So $d = c-rm$. As $a$ divides $c$ and $m$, and $-r$ is an integer,  $a$ divides $d$. Likewise as $b$ divides both $c$ and $m$, it follows that $b$ divides $d$. So both $a$ and $b$ divide $d$. But $m$ is LCM of $a$ and $b$ and $d< m$. What can you say about $d$?

Comment: then d must be equal to 0!!!

Comment: ...Exactly! You got it